# How to rewrite url website in nginx when many site in server

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

i want rewrite url in nginx but server Ubuntu has many site.

rewrite friendly url in php website.

Answer (score 0):

You may use rewrite rules from nginx possibilities. For example

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.site1.com site1.com;


   location=/your-url
   {

     rewrite a.php=$1 ^my-desires([0-9]+)$ break;
   }

   ....
   ....
}
```

Also, you can look about rewrite module from https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/